# how to represent values of stock in a polynom?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

i'm doing a project in genetic algorithms and we need to build a software that chooses set of stocks based on their history.
we need to do it on genetic programming which means we need a fitness function and a chromosome.
right i thought to the fitness function by the positive diffrence between the avarge history of the stock and it real value.(so if it's matched it will be 0 ).
does anyone have any idea how to express the chromosome?

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't seem to be well-defined. The fitness function you mentioned would give you a selection of stocks whose prices hover around their actual values, provided you know the actual value of the stocks. 
Other possibilities:

First scenario:You are trying to select a set of the most promising stocks based on its historical performance i.e. maximize expected return and/or minimize variance/risk.  If the number of possible stocks to choose from is not large, simplest option is to have a binary string: 0 representing no selection and 1 representing selection. The position corresponds to the index of the stock. If you have a very large number of possible stocks to choose from, you can encode the labels/indices of the stocks as your chromosome. This might mean a variable-length chromosome if you do not have a maximum cap on the number of stocks to be selected, and it would be harder to code.

Fitness function (to be maximized) would be the sum of (expected return - standard deviation)  of selected stocks. The expected return  could be formulated in two ways: expected future price - current price, or current price - underlying value (if you know the underlying value, that is). Expected future price can be estimated from historical data (e.g. fit a simple curve of ur choice, or apply ARIMA and extend to next time points). The standard deviation can be estimated directly from historical data.

If your chromosome is binary (values are 0/1), once you have the expected return and standard deviation, a simple dot product would do the computation needed.  I suppose there may be a cap also on the number of stocks selected, in which case you have a constrained optimization problem. You can represent constraints as penalties in the fitness.

The problem is essentially a binary integer linear program (BILP) and you can benchmark the GA against other bilp solvers. With a decent mixed integer linear programming solver (e.g. symphony, gurobi, ibm cplex,etc), you can usually solve large problems faster than with a GA.

Second scenario:  You are trying to find how many of what stocks to buy at current price to maximise expected return . Your chromosome here would be non negative integers, unless you want to represent shorting. The fitness would still be the same as in item (1), i.e. sum of prices of selected stocks, averaged over time, minus standard deviation of historical prices of selected stocks over time. The problem becomes an integer linear programming problem. Everything else is the same as in item (1). Again, if the number of stocks from which you can choose is large, you will find that a MILP solver would serve you much, much better than a GA.

Further, GP (genetic programming) is sufficiently different from GA. 
If you are trying to evolve a stock selection strategy, or an expression that predicts stock prices in the future, you actually a GP. For the stock selection problem, a ga wld b sufficient.